# Can't serialize plain struct with Nullable fields

Tags: unity, c#, serialization, json

I try to save game data in `PlayerPrefs` as JSON string. I [read in documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html) that I can use plain struct/class with `[Serializable]` attribute but it doesn't work...

First I thought that data didn't arrive so I start to debug and watch values and saw that data is arrived. Then thought that (may be) `SetString` method is asynchronous, but when I evaluate the expression `JsonUtility.ToJson(GameData)` it showed me empty string again

Also I tried:

- add `[SerializeField]` to both fields
- use `int` instead of `enum`
- add/remove `[Serializable]` attribute for enum

[image: Code editor screenshot showing x is null]

The problems disappears when I don't use `Nullable` fields. Is there any workaround to use `Nullable` fields?

````cs
using System;
using UnityEngine;

[Serializable]
public enum FPSValues {
    High = 60,
    Low = 30
}

[Serializable]
public struct GameData {
    public FPSValues? FPS;
    public bool? IsAudioEnabled;
}

public class GameDataManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public static GameData GameData;

    private void Awake() {
        Load();
    }
    
    public static void Save() {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("GameData", JsonUtility.ToJson(GameData));
        var x = PlayerPrefs.GetString("GameData");
    }

    private void Load() {
        var x = JsonUtility.FromJson<GameData>(PlayerPrefs.GetString("GameData"));
        GameData = x;
    }
}
```
````

Comment: You said that "remove "?" symbol" did not fix the problem, but that seems to be contradicted by "The problems disappears when I don't use Nullable fields." - do you need to amend the list of things you tried based on this observation?

Comment: @DMGregory I removed only for one field, I thought it would work for this field but it didn't work. Now I tried to remove from both of fields and it works. BTW I can remove this point from list if it is confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can gain the effect of the nullable just by updating your enums:

```cs
[System.Serializable]
public enum FPSValues : byte {
    Unset = 0,
    High = 60,
    Low = 30,
}

[System.Serializable]
public enum OptionalBool : byte {
    Unset,
    False,
    True
}
```

Now instead of `if (FPS != null) ...` you'd write `if (FPS != FPSValues.Unset) ...` and the rest is pretty much the same as working with your unmodified enums.

In fact, it even lets you handle all three cases in a single switch:

```cs
switch (FPS) {
    case FPSValues.Low: /*...*/ break;
    case FPSValues.High: /*...*/ break;
    default: /*...*/ break;
}
```

While with a nullable you'd need to write the slightly more cumbersome:

```cs
if (FPS.HasValue) {
   switch (FPS.Value) {
       case FPSValues.Low: /*...*/ break;
       case FPSValues.High: /*...*/ break;
   }
} else {
   /* Default behaviour... */
}
```

This plays nicely with the Unity serializer for both JSON and Inspector parameters (the same logic is used for both, so a good way to check whether a type is supported is to see if you can edit it in the Inspector).

And as a bonus: it uses less memory! The previous nullable versions used 2-8 bytes each (due to adding separate storage for the null flag, plus alignment), while these new enums fit in just a single byte.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I read some solutions which are more or less look like your method. But it is good for small data, imagine that in future I will store more complex data where fields can be also complex structs. It was just basic data to show my problem. Anyway thank you for your advice and trick about `byte` for enums I didn't know it

Comment: If you have more complex data structures that need to be optional, it may be worth making them `class` type instead of `struct`. Then you can use `[SerializeReference]` to store a null, or implement custom serialization/deserialization callbacks if you need bespoke behaviour.

Comment: I already tried it to use class instead of struct and use `[SerializeReference]` for fields after reading [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeReference.html) but it also doesn't work [RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaR1O.png)

Comment: You've misunderstood. `class` is not a keyword that you put on a container that magically makes nullable struct members inside it serializable now. Nullable structs are not serializable using Unity's serializer. Full stop. `[SerializeReference]` is useful if you have a *member* that is a *class* type (not a nullable struct), and you want it to be able to be serialized as null rather than as a default instance.

Comment: Oh, you mean that it will work if field itself be a class (for example `[SerializeReference] public GameObject target`)? Can you please give small example if I'm wrong again, I'm new in C# come here from JS :)

Comment: `public class Foo { public int a; }`  `public class Bar { public Foo foo; }` By default, when you serialize `Bar` and then deserialize it, `foo` will contain a non-null instance with `foo.a = 0`. If you put `[SerializeReference] Foo foo` then when you deserialize it, `foo` will be null, rather than an instance with default values.

Comment: Thank so much! Now it is much more clear

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code. x is null in your example because that line of code did not yet get executed. If you add another line after it, you will see that x will be of type `GameData`.

```
public static void Save() {
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("GameData", JsonUtility.ToJson(GameData));
    var x = PlayerPrefs.GetString("GameData");
    Debug.Log(x);
}
```

To make your code read easier, don't name the variable the exactly the same as your class/ struct, enum. Use _ or different case to make sure when you mean the variable and when the class.

Comment: Thank you! But it is not a problem. I wrote `x` because I got empty string when evaluate `JsonUtility.ToJson(GameData)`. As far as I understood this is due to what I use `Nullable` fields in struct. Because when I remove them it works. Are `Nullable` fields not allowed to serialize?